# Bootstrap columns throws off html width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building an Angular2 app and I am working in a component that takes up the whole width of the page.  When I have this in the html file for my component the page is fine:

```
<div class="row">
    (literally nothing in here)
</div>
```

But when I add a `col-md-12` div in side this row, my html get thrown off and becomes too wide for the page and allows me to scroll horizontally, which I don't want to be able to do:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        (literally nothing in here)
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should be wrapping your `<div class="row">` tags in `<div class="container">` OR `<div class="container-fluid">`, like so.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, use `container-fluid` which will allow your content to span the entire width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Always use `container-fluid` instead of `col-md-12` when you want to use full width of the container, that's the fix you are looking for. From [Bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/):

> Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

Comment: `col-md-12` isn't necessarily the issue here, it itself isn't causing the layout width. The issue is however, definitely the lack of a `container` or `container-fluid` classes.